# GPG Error Code 2

Tags: php, encryption, gnupg

GPG is always returning 2 at the result. My code is as follows

`$cmd = "/usr/bin/gpg -a --recipient $to -e -o $outfile $infile";`

Where outfile is the file where the encrypted data will be written and infile is the unencrypted data.

I don't know why this is happening. Can anyone please tell me what's wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GPG is asking whether you want to continue on with the encryption using an unsigned key. Since no user can input `Y` it produces an error.

To fix this put the following switches

`--yes` and `--always-trust`

Answer (score 4):

See this message: http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2008-January/032410.html

It appears to be a permission problem. gpg is trying to access a directory that it can't have access to, so it fails with a fatal error. (error code 2)

You can fix that by specifying a *homedir* directive with a directory writable by gpg. Like this:

```
$cmd = "/usr/bin/gpg -a --recipient $to -e -o $outfile $infile --homedir /path/to/dir";
```

Information from `man gpg`:

> --homedir directory
>   Set the name of the home directory to directory
>
> If this option is not used it defaults to
>   "~/.gnupg". It does not make sense to
>   use this in a options file. This also
>   overrides the environment variable
>   $GNUPGHOME.

Comment: so the path do the directory would be something like `/something/something/.gnupg`? I also set the `GNUPGHOME` to the path to the .gnupg folder

Comment: From the link: "Also, for some reason, setting `GNUPGHOME` directly does not work.". I think you should use --homedir. Yes, it would be something like it. The directory needs to be writable by your script, though.

Comment: I figured it out... i needed `--yes` and `--always-trust` because it's asking for input but since it's in php it doesn't get that input hence it breaks.

Comment: @thiago I tried the yes and always-trust...no luck there.  I'm trying to do the homedir method now, but I'm confused as to what I want to set it to...?

Answer (score 3):

You also might want to concider adding key to trusted keys list:

```
gpg.exe --edit-key KEY_NAME
trust
5 (level of trust)
Y
Save
```

I've had some problems of `--always-trust` parameter not functioning properly on XP windows, this helped me solve the problem.

Comment: Doesn't the trust level only apply to verifying message/file signatures?  I thought a key had to be signed, either by you or others whose key you've signed, to be able to use it as an encryption recipient.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but for the decoding command

At first and general, you can get the error message by redirecting stderr to stdout.

```
$cmd = "/usr/bin/gpg -a --recipient $to -e -o $outfile $infile 2>&1";
```

Then you can modify gpg's parameters to suit your needs. Because I had a files encrypted with a key with pass phrase I had to add several parameters.

I started with

```
gpg  -o $out -d $path
```

But it complained, that it can not open tty, then with --no-tty it outputs some other errors and finally the command for decoding files with key with pass phrase is

```
gpg --batch --passphrase $pass_phrase --no-tty -o $outfile -d $path_to_encoded_file
```

I hope this helps someone.