# Using GPG to encrypt .gzip file in CHMOD 777 directory within PHP - Error code 2

Tags: php, gnupg

To begin, I've tried the two solutions found here: [GPG Error Code 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350442/gpg-error-code-2) The best I could.  I don't quite understand what to set `--homedir directory` to, so maybe I can still try that method if somebody can help me figure out what to set it to.

In the meantime, I know that GPG works fine in the terminal as Root - and the file is created as expected.  It's this code that fails with error code 2:

```
<?php
$file = "/path/to/file.gzp";
system("gpg --encrypt --recipient 'shack' --yes --always-trust " . $file, $returnValue);
?>
```

Anybody know the issue?

Comment: Can you post [a link](http://pastebin.com/) to the output of `ls -l /path/to/file.gzp; strace php gpg-encrypt.php` ?

Comment: you can redirect the output like so: `sh -c 'ls -l /path/to/file.gzp; strace php gpg-encrypt.php' > file-to-upload 2>&1`. Please note that this expects the above php file to be `gpg-encrypt.php` in the current directory, so substitute its name with the real one.

Comment: Here ya go, sorry I didnt get it before!  http://pastebin.com/GU9fsx6V

Comment: @phihag and guess what... that worked.  So, I'm not too sure why it won't work otherwise...  If I run that PHP file from my browser, it fails.

Comment: Oh, I'm terribly sorry, that output is not as helpful as I had hoped - my mistake, sorry! When you just enter `gpg --encrypt --recipient 'shack' --yes --always-trust /path/to/file.gz` *as the user php's running on* (with `su www-data`, you'll get a shell), do you get an error message?. Feel free to [contact me](http://phihag.de/) via Jabber, icq, or Facebook - this is probably a misconfiguration issue and may require additional information.

Comment: @phihag will skype chat you shortly...

Comment: Skype is kind of cumbersome for me, but I'm on there now. Unfortunately, I can't find a `Shackrock` Skype user ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a permission issue; when php runs on the webserver, it executes as the user `www-data` , `nobody` or so, not root. Configure the pgp keys with the user php's running on (you can test in an interactive shell with `su www-data`). You may want to specify `--homedir /some/directory` to store and access the keys in another directory.