# php shell_exec doesn't work in browser but works in terminal

Tags: php, shell-exec

I'm working on shell_exec and it doesn't run in browser but works in terminal. Here's my code:

```
<?php
    echo 1;

    shell_exec ("gpg --output /home/datafeeding/testing/sampledick.xls.gpg --encrypt --recipient rtalplacido@yahoo.com /opt/jasperserver-3.5.0/apache-tomcat/webapps/JavaBridge/reports/sampledick.xls");

    echo 2;
    echo "<br>";

?>
```

It `echo 2`, it just passes through the shell exec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

> Note: This function is disabled when PHP is running in safe mode.

Also, add full path you gpg binary - /usr/bin/gpg

See this post: [GPG Error Code 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350442/gpg-error-code-2)

Comment: Okay, try exec() - it has return_var variable which you can check. Maybe you have to add path to gpg binary.

Comment: Just use pull path:
`exec('/usr/bin/gpg --output /home/datafeeding/testing/sampledick.xls.gpg --encrypt --recipient rtalplacido@yahoo.com /opt/jasperserver-3.5.    0/apache-tomcat/webapps/JavaBridge/reports/sampledick.xls', $output, $return); var_dump($output, $return);`

Comment: hi! it inputs array(0) { } int(2)

Comment: It returns 2 and it means error: "Misuse of shell builtins" - seams like it couldn't find gpg. try this code: `exec('$(which gpg) --output /home/datafeeding/testing/sampledick.xls.gpg --encrypt --recipient rtalplacido@yahoo.com /opt/jasperserver-3.5. 0/apache-tomcat/webapps/JavaBridge/reports/sampledick.xls', $output, $return); var_dump($output, $return);`

Comment: I have updated my answer. You should add --yes, --always-trust and --homedir

Comment: exec('$(which gpg) --yes --always-trust --homedir --output /home/datafeeding/testing/sampledick.xls.gpg --encrypt --recipient rtalplacido@yahoo.com /opt/jasperserver-3.5. 0/apache-tomcat/webapps/JavaBridge/reports/sampledick.xls', $output, $return); var_dump($output, $return);

Comment: I think your command is not intended to output anything. Check return code of $return. Has it changed? It should be 0 on success.

Comment: Try to google it. PHP shell environment is different from your normal user one - that's why it is failing. As alternative, you could try http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gnupg.php

Comment: It doesnt change, still int(2). When i use that exec command in terminal it works.

Comment: But it can't be done by shell_exec? By the way I tried /usr/local/php/bin/php /opt/lampp/htdocs/ftp.php and it encrypted the file successfully

Comment: I tried my best to help you. Maybe somebody else knows. /usr/local/php/bin/php???

Comment: `which gpg` will not work directly in the script, if the shell could find it it would execute it. Enter the command directly in your shell, it should give you the complete path to the gpg binary, something like `/usr/bin/gpg` (this is the output on MY machine, don't put it directly in your script, run `which gpg`, it may be someplace else on your machine).

Comment: Why will not it work? Anything you run in CLI, could be run in script. Save this line in file: `$(which ls) -lah` and execute it. It works!

Comment: Does user affect executing gpg shell_exec in browser? Because I'm using root in terminal while daemon in browser. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Okay, when you are root, become www user and execute your command in terminal to see the result. I think the reason are permissions of /home/datafeeding/testing/ directory

Comment: i dont have a www, daemon only. ok will try it :)

Comment: @RomanNewaza the user the httpd is running might have a different path environment set. `which` only finds binaries which are in the path, if gpg is not in the path of the www user, it can't find it. If it is in the path, PHP could run it. So there is no gain by using `which` in the PHP script.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider what if there's no www user? daemon user is used by the browser to run it. and i dont know its password :O need help thanks!

Comment: Check your webserver configuration regarding user

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, I got your point, you are right about which command.

Comment: It is very easy to check under which user your webserver is running - execute `ps aux | grep apache`.

Comment: I already know it, but my problem is how to change its permission that will allow gpg

Comment: I bet you are able to run it. Try this for test: `exec("gpg -h", $out, $ret); var_dump($out, $ret);`. I think HTTPD can't write to output file. Check with `ls -l /home/datafeeding/testing/sampledick.xls.gpg`. As you run it under different user before, the file has no write permissions for www user. So change permissions: `chgrp -R your-www-group-name /home/datafeeding/testing/ && chmod -R g+w /home/datafeeding/testing/`

Comment: i changed permission of my input and output folder also my php script to chgrp daemon which is the www user and i'm still using var_dump. output is still array(0) { } int(2)

Comment: but you're right, i can run gpg but can't output file. when i run it in terminal it doesn't have a permission to write and execute for grp and other users

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -lR /home/datafeeding/testing/` here?

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx 1 root daemon  231 Dec  3 12:06 ftp.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root daemon 3584 Dec  6 06:49 sampledick.xls

Comment: Has it created the output file?

Comment: no output file. i also tried earlier a shell_exec that copies a file from another folder to my folder and it was successful.

Comment: It doesn't matter which user you use, but yes, I use www-data user. What works? GPG! What else?!

Comment: so the problem is in apache. what I mean about "what works?" is what code did you use to encrypt.

Comment: Actually, this is not HTTPD problem. Before, I also had status 2 because www user had no key, so I logged in over terminal as www user, created key with `gpg --gen-key`, then I deleted output file (!important), otherwise it will fail because it prompts for user input to overwrite the file and, finally, it worked - got status 0 and the file was created. I used test command like this: `exec('/usr/bin/gpg --verbose --output /tmp/save.bin.test --recipient www-data --armor --encrypt /home/roman/save.bin', $output, $return);`

Comment: i see, but what if i already chmod 777 the ~/.gnupg for the keys? i dont have access to www user

Comment: changing permission of ~/.gnupg will not help you as you do it for your normal user which is different from HTTTPD user. Do you have root access? BTW, you can check your www user keys with `exec('/usr/bin/gpg --list-keys', $output, $return);`

Comment: I have a root access, I thought changing its permission will allow me. And you're right, I dont have any key for www user. array(0) { } int(2)

Comment: Or can I import a key using exec('/usr/bin/gpg --import import_key.gpg');? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can use import or just execute the following to create new ones: 1. `sudo su`; 2. `su your-www-user`; 3. `gpg --gen-key`.

Comment: It inputs array(0) { } int(2). Both in listing keys and importing so it means there's something missing but it seems to be okay. When I logged in as my www-user it says that "This account is currently not available".

Comment: I think my www-user is locked that's why I can't access it

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you if you are not able to hack your system. I bet you have no www-user.

Comment: I have my www-user, it prints when I'm executing whoami

Comment: That message ("This account is currently not available") is printed by nologin app. It is set in /etc/passwd for www-user. Change it from nologin to /bin/bash and try again ;-)

Comment: No problem! What did you do? :)

Comment: su -s /bin/bash root -c "/usr/bin/gpg --output /home/datafeeding/testing/sampledick.xls.gpg --encrypt --recipient rtalplacido@yahoo.com /opt/jasperserver-3.5. 0/apache-tomcat/webapps/JavaBridge/reports/sampledick.xls"

Comment: Do you run it over Apache? How about root password?