# GnuPG Encryption is not working with Process error Code 2

Tags: c#, process, gnupg

I have the below code where this encryption code works fine (creating encrypted file) when it is called through `Command Prompt` and the same is not working when it is in `Console Application`.

```
var destFilePath = @"D:\test.gpg";
var recipient = "test@test.com";
var sourceFilePath = @"D:\test.txt";
var proc = new Process
           {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "cmd.exe",
                    Arguments = string.Format("gpg2 --output {0} --encrypt --recipient {1} {2}",
                                                destFilePath, recipient, sourceFilePath),
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG"
                }
            };

            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
            int rc = proc.ExitCode;
            proc.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(rc.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
```

which is returning error code 2 in the ExitCode

Any Ideas would help!

Comment: you need to call the gpg2 exe not cmd.exe

Comment: What's the error message? Why do many people keep leaving out the actual error messages they get when asking for help?

Comment: also you might need to delimit your variables, so add '' around them

Comment: @MikeT, It is not working working even changing to `gpg2.exe`

Comment: @ray, I am not getting any error messages

Comment: @MikeT, Delimiting also doesn't works

Comment: What is the specific failure? Do you get a specific exit code from the `Process`? Does it just hang and never returns from the `WaitForExit()` call? What *actually* happens? There's always an error indicator/message somewhere.

Comment: @MikeT, In console the output is `2`

Comment: have a look here then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350442/gpg-error-code-2

Comment: Note that you should be *very* careful when implementing security-related features into programs. It's *very* easy to screw up.

Comment: Are you running the application under another system user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [GPG Error Code 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350442/gpg-error-code-2):

> GPG is asking whether you want to continue on with the encryption
>   using an unsigned key. Since no user can input Y it produces an error.
>
> To fix this put the following switches
>
> `--yes` and `--always-trust`

its been a while since i used GPG but the order of arguments is normally not important as long as they are named

which would give you something like this

```
FileName = "gpg2.exe",
Arguments = $"--output {destFilePath} --encrypt --yes --always-trust --recipient {recipient} {sourceFilePath}",
```

note: that's C#6 formatting which is slightly easier to read